# How to create a printed photo album on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, printing, photos

I am looking for a simple (and, of course, cheap) way to create a printed "photo album" on Windows 10 Home.  I can get the "Photos" app to create an "album" (a bit flaky, but adequate), but there is no way to then print it than I can figure.  (I want to print a bunch of pictures to show to an 80-year-old man and let him have to keep.  Having an online "album" is not what I need.)

Comment: Could you post an image of what result you require?

Comment: @RaghuRanganathan - I don't know where to get an image (without having to make an album first).  I simply want 4-6 images printed per standard 8.5x11 page.

Comment: @fixer1234 - A simple Google search will bring up hundreds of irrelevant pages, most for schemes which, when you try them, don't work on W10.

Comment: Give [it a look](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33296/116815)... You may install  [`MikTex`](https://miktex.org/) and [`TexMaker`](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) (free open source) to deal with the LaTeX`document. Do not get scared by the code, you have only to modify the name of the picture files and the text (maybe the size of the pictures...). Then you will have a pdf that you can print by yourself or give to a typography.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without having way more information to go on, it sounds like standard picture printing in Windows is what you're after.

Stick all the pictures you want into a folder, select 4 of them, right click > print:
[image]

Select a printer, paper size and select a layout from the right hand side (I've selected 9x13(4) based on you wanting ~4/page):
[image]

Repeat for any other pictures you want.

Job done :)

Comment: This works, which is better than I can say for several other schemes.  I even tried Target's service and SmugMug (which is promoted by Flickr), and neither one could be made to work for other than simple page-per-photo cases.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: +100 (if I could), excellent answer without needing to master any apps. I used this tip to print multiple copies per page of the same image. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As someone has already answered about the `Print` option of Windows 10, that is pretty fine to do what you wanted. But there are some limitations, like you can keep only 1, 2, 4, 8, 12 or 60 photos in a page with that method. So, if you want to create a album page with custom/odd no. of photos, then it doesn't allow you to do so.

Also, with that method, when you create some layouts of photos in a page, you have to print them instantly, else you will not be able to save the state and you will have to start from beginning in later time. If you are OK with those limitations, then you can go through that method as that is the easiest and cheapest method.

But, there are many third party software which allow you to do more than that and there are many such software which are fully free of cost. You can find a bunch of them if you google it. Still I am suggesting you two of the cheapest (literally free of cost) and easiest software that you may try for your purpose. They have some advanced features like creating custom layout, photo editing and adding frames which may be useful.

One of them is [ArcSoft Print Creations](http://download.arcsoft.com/downloads/printcreations/arcsoft/printcreations.exe) which can help you make gorgeous photo album books.

[image]

Another one is the [Pixum Photo World](https://www.pixum.co.uk/photo-book/danke?os=win) software. This has some advanced tool and custom layouts which will be very much helpful for creating a nice presentation. Still using this software is very easy and straightforward.

[image]

*Reference: The images associated with different software are collected from their official site.*

Answer (score 1):

**Choice of application**

There are endless "album" applications that are already optimized for standard photo and paper sizes.  If your images are all a standard size and you're happy with the layout options those apps offer, they may be the best solution for you.  In my own case, I've never bothered with those apps because I usually have cropped images that they don't handle well.  I also often have a particular output or layout in mind, and find that I need to fight a simple app to get what I want, if it can do it at all.

When I haven't needed fancy borders or other special effects, I've just used the free [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/) for this.  It's been my go-to utility for all image work that doesn't require the heaviest-duty tools of Photoshop.

It offers a huge range of image-related options, so it may look more complicated than a dedicated album app.  However, you can easily navigate to the features you want.  There are many options and things you can set or adjust, so again, the interface may look more complicated than an app where you just select your images, pick a couple of options, and output your album.

However, setting up for a specific job is actually pretty straightforward, and you only need to do it once.  It then gives you much more control to customize the output if you don't want to just run with the default settings.

It has a built-in "Contact Sheet" option, that does what you describe.  There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.kearc.com/southernstringband/Irfanview/irfanproof.html), but I'll describe the procedure, and include an example of what I often encounter, and why I prefer this over album software.  You can decide whether it is too much additional complexity for your own needs.  I'll also suggest a couple of things that will improve the output appearance, even if you use an album app.

**The Contact Sheet feature**

When you install Irfanview, you have the option to create a shortcut to the Thumbnails UI, which is where you find this feature.  If you don't create that shortcut, you can open it from the Irfanview main menu: `File | Thumbnails`.

**How to**

1. **Find and select the images to include.**

   In the Thumbnails UI, you navigate to where the images are stored and select the ones you want to include:

[image]

My navigation panel may look unusual because I run Irfanview on Linux using Wine; what you see is the Linux directory structure.

2. **Select contact sheet and setup what you want.**

   From the menu: `File | Create contact sheet from selected files`:

[image]

This brings up a setup menu, which you only need to do once unless you want to tweak it for different groups of images:

[image]

The image above shows the many options you can adjust or include:

- paper size and orientation
- resolution (in the 64 bit version, the page size limit is 25,000 x 25,000 pixels)
- number of rows and columns of images per page
- the margins and image spacing (what's left defines the available size for each image)
- various color and labeling options
- type of output you want, etc.

  3. **Select the printer options.**

  Then you click `Create`.  If you've chosen to print, you get a printer setup window that only needs to be setup once unless you want to tweak it:

[image]

It includes a preview, as well as printer options.

4. **Use the options to adjust anything you don't like.**

   This is the part you can't do in a simple album app.  The random images I picked for this post happened to be cropped in many different sizes and aspect ratios.  Irfanview makes each image the maximum size that will fit in the predefined windows, so in this case, the sizes look mismatched.

   If I was actually making an album and had this situation, I would group the images with ones of similar aspect ratio and generate the pages in batches so they look uniform.  With normal photos, you would see this if you have a mix of portrait and landscape images, so I would group those by orientation.

   In this case, the preview illustrated that my odd images and settings wouldn't look great, so I selected a group of images that were close in aspect ratio and tweaked the layout a little:

[image]

Notice that there isn't a uniform margin around each image.  Typically, there won't be an ideal relationship between the aspect ratio of the images in a matrix layout, and the aspect ratio of the paper.  The Thumbnail Spacing and Margin settings on the Contact Sheet setup page let you optimize this (which I haven't bothered to do for this answer).  There are additional options on the Printer Settings page to optimize this.

**Available Save options.**

You can save the sheets as images to see what they will look like before printing, or to reprint them later.  For a photo album, pick a decent resolution setting, and set the printer for photo or high quality print with photo quality paper.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there has not been an easy way to do this for several years. Microsoft tends to remove certain old features which were not particularly popular. I may be incorrect, but I think that the only practical way to do this using stock Windows software is to open up a blank image of the proper dimension in Paint, then add on the images one-by-one `(Paste > Paste from)`. If you have no qualms about using third-party software, there are many free services available online which were built for this purpose, such as [PhotoJoiner](https://www.photojoiner.net/), [BeFunky](https://www.befunky.com/features/collage-maker/), and [Online Image Editor](http://www.online-image-editor.com/).

Edit: As somebody mentioned above, there is, in fact, a way to do this using the Print option in the Windows context menu. However, I believe that there is a rather small limitation placed upon the amount of images allowed on one page.

Answer (score 0):

You may create albums using
[Adobe Bridge CC](https://www.adobe.com/sea/products/bridge.html).
Bridge is trialware, but the trial never expires.

With Bridge you can create contact sheets and save them as PDF which you
may print anywhere.

You have a very detailed control over the format of the generated PDF file
as regarding layout, grid and margins, header and footer, watermark,
PDF properties and colors.

See the Adobe article
[Create PDF contact sheet in the Output workspace](https://helpx.adobe.com/bridge/using/output-module-pdf-contact-sheet.html)
for more information.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Adobe Bridge is more than a simple media browser, but is rather
a full file management system. 
See the lifewire article
[How To Use Adobe Bridge CC 2017](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-adobe-bridge-cc-4128720).

[image]

Comment: Who downvoted and why ?

Comment: Well, if you had known why you would have known even who `:-)`. BTW (not me). Note that each answer on this page has a downvote. And the question too... I suppose because it is so similar to a software recommendation ...

Comment: @Hastur: Such systematic downvoting is really overdoing it.

Comment: Some people downvote answers because they're better than theirs, which is contrary to the spirit of the site. +1 to negate the anonymous downvote...  (cc@Hastur: Hint, hint, ...)